# How to run DVFS on gem5?

Tags: gem5

I ran the gem5 and could run ARM and full system on geme5.now I need to run DVFs on gem5 but I do not do it and looking sites for example :

1.http://www.gem5.org/Running_gem5#Experimenting_with_DVFS
2.http://www.gem5.org/docs/html/classDVFSHandler.html

but I don't understand  and I don't know how to run DVFS on gem5.please help me and guide how I can do it and introduction site or reference for it?